# Doctrine - create multiple queries

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to create multiples queries in Doctrine.
I create two variables, each one begin with the same query. Then I want to have two distincts queries. But if I modify the first query, the second one get the changes, acting like pointers.

I use Symfony 3.0 , Doctrine 2.4.8

```
$queryA = $queryB = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:MyEntity')
            ->createQueryBuilder('me')
            ->join('me.foo', 'f')
            ->where('me.status = :valid')
            ->andWhere('foo.bar = :bar')
            ->setParameters([
                'valid' => 'valid',
                'bar' => 'bar',
            ]);

dump($queryB);

$results = $queryA
    ->join('me.lol', 'lol')
    ->getQuery()->getResult();

dump($queryB);exit;
```

Now the $queryB has the join `me.lol`. I know this is caused by the $queryA = $queryB. But I want to factor my code.

How can I have two separates variables with the same query ? When I use a join with the $queryA doesn't affect the $queryB ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone `$queryA`, cloning will give you distinct `queryB` object which is same as `queryA` but not a reference to `queryA`:

```
$queryB = clone $queryA;
```